# 2D vector with very large size

Tags: c++, ubuntu, g++

i have defined a 2 dimention vector in c++ that its sizes are too large. the voctor definition is like this:

```
vector<vector<string> > CommunityNodes(3600, vector<string>(240005));
```

when i run the program, i have the following error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
what():  std::bad_alloc
```

before i run the program, i take the following command in console line that specify the stack size would be unlimited:

```
ulimit -s unlimited
```

but again i have the allocation error.how can i define such big vector in c++?

Comment: You're trying to allocate an array of strings of size: 823.992 mb for what reason exactly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's assume an implementation of `std::string` containing one 32-bit pointer to its contents, one 32-bit int for the current length of the string, and one 32-bit int for the current allocation size.

That gives us 12 bytes per string * 240005 strings per row * 3600 rows, which works out to 9.7 gigabytes -- considerably more than you can deal with on a 32-bit implementation. Worse, an implementation might easily pad that 12-byte string out to 16 bytes, thus increasing the memory needed still more.

If you go to a 64-bit implementation, you can address more memory, but the size is likely to double, so you'd need roughly 20 gigabytes of memory just to store the arrays of empty strings. Add some actual contents, and you need even more (and, again, the string could easily be padded to be larger still).

So, yes, with a 64-bit implementation this *can* probably be made to work, but it's impractical for most purposes. You probably want/need to find some way to reduce the number of strings you use.

Comment: i am running my peogram in a virtual machine with 32 gig accecible.the  os is ubuntu 10.04 64 bit. but still i have the problem. isnt any other solution?

Comment: +1 for the answer; if you do not need all the strings, you can try std::map<int, std::map<int, std:string>> or something similar. If you need the several gigs of data, you might want to use a database?

Answer (score 0):

An attempt to pre-allocate that much space suggests that you are taking the wrong approach to the problem.  I suspect that *most* of the nodes in the double vector are going to be empty.  If that is the case, you would be much better off with something like a double map instead of a double vector:

```
std::map< int, std::map< int, std::string > > CommunityNodes();
```

Then you only create the entries you must have, instead of preallocating the entire array.

**Please Note:** using the '[]' operator will automatically create a node, even if you don't assign anything to it.  If you don't want to create the node, then use 'find()' instead of '[]'.